# Compiling libusb with my .c file

Tags: c, compilation

A bit of a noob question.. I'm using Linux and apt-get installed libusb-1.0 as my API uses this to talk to my USB device. If I have created an object file of my .c file, does that mean that if I use it on another machine do they need to first apt-get installed libusb-1.o, or is it in the object file?

Thanks

Comment: What is exactly the question here? Of course you need libusb installed on the other machine to be able to use its APIs.

Comment: `installed libusb-1.o,` do you mean `installed libusb-1.0,`?

Comment: sorry i meant typing the command apt-get install libusb-1.0 to install it from ubuntu sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you statically link your library to make the executable, then the executable file will contain the requisite definition of the API, bundled with the executable.